# Symfony Messenger (Messages Queue), how to get queue status?

Tags: symfony, symfony4, message-queue

I am approaching [Symfony 4.4 Message Queue](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/messenger.html) with the [Doctrine Transport](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/messenger.html#doctrine-transport).

How can I get an overall view of the queue status?

I noticed that Doctrine stores the queue in the table `messenger_messages`, obviously I could query this table to get this info, but I'm sure that Symfony has a native way to get the queue status.

I would like to get:

- the number of messages in the queue
- the number of messages that are in handling in this moment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
As of Symfony 6.2 (current release), there is now a console command to check message stats.
Source: [Checking the Number of Queued Messages Per Transport](https://symfony.com/doc/6.2/messenger.html#checking-the-number-of-queued-messages-per-transport)

---

Unfortunatley there is no native way in Symfony (as of v5.4/v6) with the default message queue.
But possible solutions are:

1. As you said, take a look in to the message table
2. Extend the console with your own commands you need (for example reading the message table and print the needed informations)
3. Using alternative message system which has this functionality already build in (such as RabbitMQ)